# Can I create a degraded mdadm raid10-near (raid 1e) array?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have three drives in my current system (all 1TB). The current setup is:

```
sdb - raid0 member (failing soon)
sdd - raid0 member
sde - backup
```

I'd like to change it so all three drives are part of a raid 1e (mdadm raid 10,n2) my main concern now is reliability, with space second, and speed as an appreciated bonus.

Looking at [this](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/stor_admin/data/cha_raid_degraded.html) manual I see I can create a "degraded" array (in this instance, with sdb and sdd) and copy the data onto it, and then add the third drive. It doesn't say anything about complex raid10 modes though. Data-wise raid 10n2 expecting 3 drives can exist with only 2, although I'm wondering if mdadm won't let me actually build and use a 10n2 array with a missing drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it with

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 -n 3 -l 10 -p n2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 missing
...
mdadm md0 -a /dev/sdc2
```

and it seemed to work.

Since it operated in degraded mode I can assume data is mirrored, and array device size is 150% the size of a drive as expected.

Comment: It worked for me with `-n 2 -l 10` as well. This created a degraded mirror array.